# Error deploying to Vercel (Error: Command "npm run build" exited with 127)

Tags: node.js, npm, vercel, parceljs

I'm using parcel-bundler for sass on my projects, I've always used npm start instead of npm run build and it has always worked for me. But this time, when I try to deploy my project on Vercel, it failed and it says "Error: Command "npm run build" exited with 127"?

I already tried setting the CI Environment Variable to false Using Vercel CLI but it's still giving me the same result.

package.json

```
{
  "name": "portfolio",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "source": "src/index.html",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "parcel src/index.html",
    "build": "parcel build src/index.html"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "sass": "^1.52.2"
  }
}
```

```
[21:07:21.022] Cloning completed: 371.994ms
[21:07:21.103] Installing build runtime...
[21:07:22.998] Build runtime installed: 1.894s
[21:07:23.868] No Build Cache available
[21:07:24.021] Installing dependencies...
[21:07:25.307] 
[21:07:25.308] added 17 packages in 1s
[21:07:25.308] 
[21:07:25.308] 2 packages are looking for funding
[21:07:25.308]   run `npm fund` for details
[21:07:25.510] Detected `package-lock.json` generated by npm 7...
[21:07:25.510] Running "npm run build"
[21:07:25.783] 
[21:07:25.784] > portfolio@1.0.0 build
[21:07:25.784] > parcel build src/index.html
[21:07:25.784] 
[21:07:25.789] sh: parcel: command not found
[21:07:25.798] Error: Command "npm run build" exited with 127
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using Parcel but it's not listed in your devDependencies. My guess is that you have it installed globally. Try adding it as a local devDependency:

`npm install --save-dev parcel`

Comment: I totally forgot about that. Thank you so much!